# What is the main advantage of storing data in session rather than storing the data in database?

Tags: java, session, web

In shopping cart application,instead of maintaining the cart items by using the session, whenever the user adding the cart items,  we can store the item in the database right?. Why in most of the places using a session is recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Shopping cart applications usually does not require a user to create an account in order to add items to the cart. Imagine a user with malicious intent to harm your application, they can just write a script to frequently add and remove items in your cart which will eventually overload your database and bring the whole application down. So its a security vulnerability.

Also genuine users themselves may add or remove items too frequently which could overload the system. They may even abandon their shopping midway with items in cart, in which case your database will keep holding unnecessary data and you would need to write an invalidation logic. So it makes sense to only update the database when the user is actually checking out their cart items.

Answer (score 0):

**It's Faster**

Every update the user is doing can be immediately updated in the local browser instead of making an HTTP request to the server + validations + DB time.

**Less load on the server**

The users can add / remove / update their shopping cart how many times they like and you don't need to scale the server for that

**Less DB storage size**

You don't need to keep all the "in-flight", "just checking" users. If a user abandons the site, you can keep the data in his browser but you don't need to allocate DB storage for it

Smaller DB + Smaller server = cheaper costs to the company.

Faster site responses = better user experience.